# How to run a common function before every serverless function like an express middleware?

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I need to run a function before running every serverless function to authenticate the user and sanitize the data. Then pass that data to the actual function like an ExpressJS middleware. Can we do something like that with serverless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see a way(a great and clean way) of implementing an "express like" middleware using lambda functions, it's a different concept.

I guess it would be a better approach to:

1. Create your custom API Gateway Authorizer (Only if you need to);
2. Authorize at API Gateway Level (IAM Policy for each user)
3. Sanitize your data in each individual Lambda

Fore more: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a standard VETO pattern (verify, enrich, transform, operation)

As Tom Melo mentioned, you can hook a cusom authorizer to an API gateway if your setup has one. If you want a single place to sanitise and transform the request, you can use a {proxy+} pattern in the API gateway to alter the message, then route to the real operation via SNS, based on the path parameters etc.

If you don't have an API Gateway, then you can chain everything together using SNS.